# Mosaic geometric menu with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I try to rendre this : 
[sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKvgy.jpg)

**PS** : if possible I'd like to animate the borders on hover

And I don't know how I can do this, I tried this :

```
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 92% 86%, 6% 100%);
```

But as you can see, the shapes are outside the div box limit.

here is my try : https://petitmaraichage.fr/

I've think of SVG but the menu content is dynamic so text can be changed...

If anyone has an idea :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know the thing I will say will be hurtful, but I doubt the methodology you have used will lead you to success. I think you will need to perform the following steps towards victory:

1. Use a canvas
2. Using the points and lines you have from the picture determine the polygones and lines you will need.
3. Based on your plans described at point 2 draw the content on the canvas, but do not forget to have a hovered state as well
4. Create a mousemove and a click Javascript event for your canvas

`

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    //Here comes your logic, the coordinates are e.clientX and e.clientY
});

canvas.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    //Here comes your logic, the coordinates are e.clientX and e.clientY
});
```

`

Comment: Hi Thank for help !! Does that mean that the text will be drawing and the links will be added in javascript ?

Comment: Yes, you can draw the text, examples here: https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/canvas_text.asp, but I think it is not necessary, because you can add links on with position absolute.